# Error registering container in Gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers

I'm trying to register a container in a project, I thought it was a passing problem, but it persisted. I created a new project still holds. I never got around to using Gitlab's registry for containers. I was following a course, when I needed to register I stopped at this error. Could someone give me some guidance.

erro:
"Docker connection error
We are having trouble connecting to the Container Registry. Please try refreshing the page. If this error persists, please review the troubleshooting documentation ."

[image: Add container]